# Expectation of inverse non central chi-squared

Tags: distributions, chi-squared-test, expected-value

If $X\sim \mathcal{N}_p(\theta,\sigma^2)$ then $X^{'}X/\sigma^2\sim$ non-central $\chi^2_p$ with non-centrality parameter $\theta^{'}\theta/\sigma^2$.

How to find out the expectation of $\sigma^2/X^{'}X$?

More specifically, how to show that $\mathbb{E}(\sigma^2/X^{'}X)$ is an increasing function of $\sigma^2$?

Comment: Given $\mathbb{E}(\sigma^2/X^{'}X) = \sigma^2 \mathbb{E}(1/X^{'}X)$, so you just need to prove $\mathbb{E}(1/X^{'}X) > 0 $.

Comment: @a_statistician I know.. But how?

Comment: $X'X = \sum(X_i^2) \ge 0$  ==> $1/X'X  \ge 0$

Comment: @a_statistician I think you are missing a point. Even if (say) $\mathbb{E} (1/X^{'}X)=1/\sigma^4$ , then $\mathbb{E} (1/X^{'}X)>0$ but overall its a decreasing function of $\sigma^2$.  We need to find theexact representation of $\sigma$ in $\mathbb{E} (1/X^{'}X)$ to be able to proceed

Comment: I am wrong, because I ignored that both parts are related to $\sigma^2$

Comment: You could perhaps write $X'X = (X-\mu+\mu)'(X-\mu+\mu) =  (X-\mu)'(X-\mu)+\mu'(X-\mu)+(X-\mu)'\mu+\mu'\mu$ $=\sigma^2 (Z'Z) +  ... \text{ etc}\:\:\:$ (where $Z$ is standard normal)

Comment: @Glen_b Sorry, but i failed to understand how this breaking will help in finding the  expectation of the inverse..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can give the expectation but I don't know for the monotonicity.

Let $C \sim \chi^2(d,\theta)$ (where $d$ degrees of freedom, and $\theta$ non-centrality parameter).

If $d > 2$, then
$$
\mathbb{E}(1/C) = \frac{1}{2}\exp(-\theta/2)\frac{\Gamma(d/2-1)}{\Gamma(d/2)}{}_1\!F_1(d/2-1,d/2,\theta/2).
$$
(I don't know for $d \leq 2$, perhaps the expectation is infinite in this case).

Check with R:

```
> df <- 10
> ncp <- 2
> x <- rchisq(1e7, df, ncp)
> mean(1/x)
[1] 0.1036415
> 
> 1/2 * gamma(df/2-1)/gamma(df/2) * exp(-ncp/2) * gsl::hyperg_1F1(df/2-1, df/2, ncp/2)
[1] 0.1036383
```

I got this formula from Gupta & Nagar's book *Matrix variate distributions*. This book provides a formula for the expectation of $\det(W)^h$ where $W$ follows a noncentral Wishart distribution, and the formula for the expectation of $1/C$ is a particular case.

Note that ${}_1\!F_1(d/2-1,d/2,\theta/2)$ has form ${}_1\!F_1(a,a+1,z)$. [Wolfram](http://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/Hypergeometric1F1/03/ShowAll.html) provides some simplification formulas for ${}_1\!F_1(a,a+1,z)$, but they make sense for $z<0$ only, as far as I can see.

## EDIT

Wait... The family of the noncentral $\chi^2$ distributions is stochastically  increasing in the noncentrality parameter. Therefore $X'X$ is stochastically decreasing in $\sigma$, and $1/X'X$ is stochastically increasing in $\sigma$. Consequently, $\mathbb{E}(1/X^{'}X)$ is an increasing function of $\sigma$, as well as $\mathbb{E}(\sigma^2/X^{'}X)$.

## EDIT 2

Thanks to a relation given in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confluent_hypergeometric_function#Kummer's_transformation), the formula for the expectation can be simplified to:
$$
\mathbb{E}(1/C) = \frac{1}{2}\frac{\Gamma(d/2-1)}{\Gamma(d/2)}{}_1\!F_1(1,d/2,-\theta/2).
$$
Now, in view of the [integral representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confluent_hypergeometric_function#Integral_representations) of ${}_1\!F_1$, it is clear that ${}_1\!F_1(a,b,z)$ is increasing in $z$.

Comment: Your formula is supported by Equation (10.9) in Paolella's _Intermediate Probability_, which gives arbitrary moments of chi-square variates.