# For a general multivariate normally distributed $\boldsymbol{X}$, what is the expectation of $1/(\boldsymbol{X}^T \boldsymbol{X})$

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, expected-value, integral, quadratic-form

For $\boldsymbol{X} \sim \mathcal{N}(\boldsymbol{\mu}, \boldsymbol{\Sigma})$, where $\boldsymbol{\mu} \in \mathbb{R}^N$, $\boldsymbol{\Sigma} \in \mathbb{R}^{N \times N}$ is positive definite, how to calculate the value of $\mathbb{E}[1/(\boldsymbol{X}^T\boldsymbol{X})]$?

I think the difficulty here is that $\boldsymbol{\Sigma}$ is any positive definite matrix. So the entries in $\boldsymbol{X}$ could be correlated. Even if $\boldsymbol{\Sigma}$ is a diagonal matrix, the diagonal entries in $\boldsymbol{\Sigma}$ could also be different, which makes it hard to use the conclusions of non-central $\chi^2$ distribution.

Comment: Does your expectation in the last line refer to a matrix inverse or to inverting each element?  I assume the former, but checking doesn't hurt...

Comment: Since $\boldsymbol{X}$ is an random vector with length $N$, $\boldsymbol{X}^T\boldsymbol{X}$ is a scalar. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Expectation of inverse non central chi-squared](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/374315/expectation-of-inverse-non-central-chi-squared)

Comment: I think the difficulty here is that $\boldsymbol{\Sigma}$ is any positive definite matrix. So the entries in $\boldsymbol{X}$ could be correlated. Even if $\boldsymbol{\Sigma}$ is a diagonal matrix, the diagonal entries in $\boldsymbol{\Sigma}$ could also be different. All of these make it hard to use the conclusions of non-central $\chi^2$ distribution.

Comment: @Xi'an: the proposed duplicate does not apply. If $\boldsymbol{\Sigma}=\boldsymbol{I}$, then yes, it would - but for general $\boldsymbol{\Sigma}$, $\boldsymbol{X}^T\boldsymbol{X}$ is not noncentral $\chi^2$. I suggest you retract your close-as-duplicate vote. (Unless I am mistaken, which frequently happens. In which case, perhaps you could add a few words of explanation?)

Comment: @StephanKolassa: my point was that it is already complicated when $\mathbf{\Sigma=I_N}$.

Comment: Maybe a study of the 2x2 case could help.

Comment: @ZifengZhang If my new answer below solves your problem, please consider marking it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a second order [Taylor approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_expansions_for_the_moments_of_functions_of_random_variables).

Let $Y = X^TX$ with $X\sim \mathcal{N}(\mu, \Sigma)$. Then what you want is $\mathbb{E}(f(Y))$, where $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$. The second order Taylor approximation to this expected value is:
$$\mathbb{E}(f(Y)) \approx f(\hat{Y}) + \frac{1}{2} f''(\hat{Y}) var(Y) $$

where $\hat{Y}$ and $var(Y)$ are the expected value and variance of $Y$, respectively. The variable $Y$ above is a [quadratic form of normal random variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_form_(statistics)), and there are known formulas for both its mean and variance:

$$\hat{Y} = tr(\Sigma) + \mu^T \mu$$
$$var(Y) = 2tr(\Sigma \Sigma) + 4 \mu^T \Sigma \mu$$

Then, using the fact that $f''(x) = \frac{2}{x^3}$, the Taylor approximation becomes:

$$\mathbb{E}\left(\frac{1}{X^TX}\right) \approx \frac{1}{\hat{Y}} + \frac{var(Y)}{\hat{Y}^3}  $$

where $\hat{Y}$ and $var(Y)$ are given by the formulas above.