# Moments of inverse of a non-central chi distributed variable

Tags: probability, distributions, expected-value, moments, chi-distribution

I have a non-central chi variable $r$ with the distribution,
\begin{align}
p(r) = \frac{r^3\lambda}{(\lambda r)^{3/2}}\exp\left[-0.5(r^2 + \lambda^2)\right]I_{1/2}(r\lambda)
\end{align}

I'm looking for the following expectations.
\begin{align}
E\left[\frac{1}{r}\right]; \quad E\left[\frac{1}{r^2} \right]
\end{align}

In other words, is there a closed-form expressions for the integrals of the form,
\begin{align}
I(m) = \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{r^m} \frac{r^3\lambda}{(\lambda r)^{3/2}}\exp\left[-0.5(r^2 + \lambda^2)\right]I_{1/2}(r\lambda).
\end{align}

Thanks.

Edit :

$I_v(.)$ is the modified Bessel function of the first kind and order $v$.

Comment: You need to define your _I(.)_ notation.

Comment: @wolfies : Thanks, I did.

Comment: For the first moment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/391865/8402

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent : Thank you for the link, but it refers to non-central $\chi^2$ distributed random variable. Mine is a non-central $\chi$ variable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The density simplifies to

$$p(r)=\frac{\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi }} r e^{-(\lambda ^2+r^2)/2} \sinh (\lambda  r)}{\lambda }$$

where $\sinh$ is the hyperbolic sine function.  Integrating with *Mathematica* results in

$$E(1/r)=\frac{\text{erf}\left(\frac{\lambda }{\sqrt{2}}\right)}{\lambda }$$

$$E(1/r^2)=\frac{\sqrt{2} F\left(\frac{\lambda }{\sqrt{2}}\right)}{\lambda }$$

where $\text{erf}$ is the [error function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function) and $F$ is the [Dawson F function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dawson_function).

Higher moments don't seem to exist.

Comment: Amazing, this is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much.

Comment: Re "don't seem to exist:" $I_{1/2}(x)$ behaves like $x^{1/2}$ near the origin, whence $p(r)$ behaves like $r^2.$ It is immediate that all moments of order $-3$ or less diverge at the origin.

Comment: @whuber That helps explain it.  I was just taking *Mathematica*'s "does not converge" message at face value.  Hence the hedge of "don't seem to exist."